# How to configure button in android when I click the button it changes it's color & after clicked it will go it's default(previous) colour

Tags: android, android-studio

I already configure it for some calculation & toast message for blank input.I'm a beginner in android development.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do that and you already can do actions with the button mean that you already ser the onclick listener in the java code of the Activity right?

so in your project, you're going to create a Global boolean variable can be

Boolean default = true;

and inside the onclick listener you will say

```
if (showNewColor)
     button.setBackgroundColor(this.getResources.getColor(R.color.newColor));
else
     button.setBackgroundColor(this.getResources.getColor(R.color.defaultColor));

showNewColor = !showNewColor;
```

I hope this can help you o/

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a custom background for your button.

In your folder drawable create the next file named `background_button` and put this lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:enterFadeDuration="@integer/fade_animation_duration"
      android:exitFadeDuration="@integer/fade_animation_duration">

    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/background_button_disabled"/>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/background_button_pressed"/>
    </item>

     <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/background_button_pressed"/>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/background_button_normal"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The drawable `background_button_normal` is your default background of your button
The drawable `background_button_pressed` is your background when your button is pressed
The drawable `background_button_disabled` is your background when you put your button disabled `android:enabled="false` in your XML or in code `button.setEnabled(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the standard [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md).

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/material_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_label"/>
```

It works **automatically** with a `<selector>` for checked/enabled/disabled states. 
You can choose different [styles](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#styles) and you can customize the color with the `app:backgroundTint` attribute.

It is the default selector used in the backgroudTint.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method that will be called each time you click the button i-e in XML: `onClick()` method or in Java: `yourButton.setOnClickListener()`

`changeColor()` is the method I am using to change color of my button.

Here is the code:

Define this variable at start of your activity:

```
public static boolean applyColor = false;
Button myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_btn_id); //write your button ID in place of my_btn_id's place
```

Then set your onClickListener:

```
myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    changeColor();
}
});
```

Now define changeColor method like:

```
private void changeColor() {
        if(!applyColor) {
            myBtn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            applyColor = !applyColor;
        }
        else{
            myBtn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            applyColor = !applyColor;
        }

    }
```